which future form to use
*Situation:
I and my son are sitting at a table in a restaurant. A waiter comes to my table.
Here is the conversation:

Me: I'd like a pizza and spaghetti.
The waiter: What will your son be having?
Me: He will be having a hamburger.

Which version can I use for this context, Can I use either of them?
(1)What wil your son have?
(2)What will your son be having?
(3)What is your son going to have?
(4)What is your son having?

You can use any of them (we use either when there are only two to choose from).
The parent's reply would be "He will have a hamburger" or "He would like a hamburger" (unless they were deliberately imitating the waiter's mode of expression).

It's true that some might phrase that question as "what will your son be having?" but when you analyse it, it's a bit odd in the context. It sounds like a foregone conclusion - that the parent knows what the son will be eating, when in fact a lot has to happen before he can eat, including the waiter learning what he has already chosen. But some things just become idiomatic, so don't think too hard about it.
I feel the most natural response would be "he will have a hamburger". It isn't necessary to respond to any question with the exact same phrasing; in fact, responding in an unnecessarily long way that mirrors the phrasing of the question can sound sarcastic, like you are imitating the person. But, the way you propose is not grammatically incorrect.
This is perhaps slightly more common in US English - British English-speaking waiting staff are more like to ask "what would you like?", and get a response like "I would like..." or "may I have...". On a side note, British English speakers notice that Americans sometimes ask "can I get..." when ordering food, which sounds a little odd and perhaps a little demanding to us.
A couple of other side notes... your order of "I'd like a pizza and spaghetti" sounds like you are ordering one dish, perhaps a pizza with spaghetti on top. Spaghetti may be a non-countable noun (actually, in Italian, it's a plural term - spaghetto being the singular, but that's complicating things) but when ordering dishes in restaurants its more common to use the definite article with every dish because you are referring to the restaurant's specific dish. So, most people would say "I'd like the spaghetti", to mean the spaghetti dish listed on the menu. "A" pizza sounds ok but it's unusual for there to be only one type of pizza on a menu. The waiter is going to ask which one and then you'll have to respond with something like "the Margherita, please". So to order the two together you'd be best saying "I'd like the Margherita pizza and the spaghetti".

To UK ears, “Can I get…” doesn't just sound demanding — it's asking whether the customer can go to the kitchen and make and fetch the item him/herself!  An honest answer from the waiter might be “No, but I can get it for you…“

A margarita pizza would be interesting to see! I think you mean a margherita pizza.

@hearth thanks although if we're going to get picky it would be pizza margherita, not margherita pizza.

The reply could be as simple as
"a hamburger".

“…please.”  (In the UK, at least.  I gather that in the USA, saying ‘please’ can somehow be seen as condescending; here, it's simple politeness.)

@gidds I don't think saying 'please' would be condescending in the US - at least not by default. It could certainly be used that way if you've already been condescending, though, and you suddenly switch to "please".

@Deusovi I can't find a question hereabouts, but I've read that traditionally, in the USA, you didn't say ‘please’ because you were just giving a fellow worker the information they needed to do their job; saying ‘please‘ would sound like addressing an inferior.  That seems to be slowly changing, though.  See e.g. Lynne Murphy's take on this (and the ensuing comments).

In a place that has burgers on the menu, the wait-staff are typically rather busy, and appreciate a terse answer as much as, if not more than, a polite answer.  In other words, it is polite to be terse in certain circumstances. Reward your server with a tip, not with lip-service.

In the UK politeness is sometimes deployed as a yoke.
